# Itunes Connect: Apple watch, Your file could not be loaded please try again

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload Apple watch screenshots via itunes connect but I'm having this issue.

How to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]You have to put your app icon in this box of size 1024x1024. And your icon should not be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it again after a few hours and it works.